# How to set Date to be my column names in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on some projects and suppose I have a table with a column called `Date`. Now I want to create a new table, with `MAX(Date)` and its 5 previous months to be my columns.

For example, suppose

```
MAX(Date) = '2023-05-01'
```

in my original table, then I want the columns in my new table to be

```
'2022-12-01', ..., '2023-04-01', '2023-05-01'
```

which are 6 columns. And I want this script can work for any `MAX(Date)`, like whatever data I got, I can use this script to get a new table with 6 previous months to be the columns.

I am confused as to how to create this new table for any `Date`. If anyone has any idea, very appreciated and thanks!

I've tried some dynamic SQL but it seems no work. And I am not quite understand how it can work when creating a new table.

Comment: It's because `date` is a reserved keyword in SQL. You can escape it though: MS SQL Server supports both ISO SQL double-quotes: `"Date"`, or T-SQL square-brackets: `[Date]` - but I still think it's a bad idea because you'll have to escape it _everywhere_, but if you used a  **meaningful name**, or at least a nonreserved name like `MyDate` or `DateOfTheThing` you wouldn't have to escape it at all.

Comment: You need to rethink your design. The date is a part of the *data* not part of the *definition*. There should be a single `date` column, and the six columns should be six rows. This does not require any dynamic SQL to create or to query,whereas your design would be fiendishly difficult to do both programmatically.

Comment: @Dai `date` is reserved only by ODBC. SQL Server allows it although it's not recommended https://dbfiddle.uk/ySNe0Fsz https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to do? Creating custom date columns is a classic design mistake, there is likely a way to do what you want in a better way. Is this required data appearing in a report somewhere?

Comment: @Charlieface Ah - Because SSDT and SSMS both always color `date`/`DATE` in blue I assumed it was _always_ reserved. I was still in high-school and using MSAccess when I learned to _always_ escape it.

Comment: Just don't, such a table would be hard to work with. better write the pivot on the fly. Search stackoverflow for dynamic pivots and you'll find a lot of answers

Comment: Thanks for all of your reply. I know using a column 'Date' will be convenient. But I have another column called 'product' and 'price' for example. And I have a Excel file which contains a table, with 'product' to be rows, 'Date' for each month to be columns, and the corresponding 'price' to be its value. I just want to get the same thing in SQL.

Comment: You can produce that output with sql but that doesn't mean you should store it like it.

Comment: @Jimmy That's fine if you want to view the data that way, but _storing_ it that way in a table violates every principle of relational data design. Instead, wait to PIVOT the data until you query it for output, and use names that are consistent no matter the current date ([CurMonth], [MonthMinus1], [MonthMinus2], etc).

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the most important point of *should* you do this...

Setting up some test data:

```
create table #sourceTable
(
    [Date] date
)

insert into #sourceTable values
('2023-07-01'),
('2023-06-01'),
('2023-05-01'),
('2023-04-01'),
('2023-03-01'),
('2023-02-01'),
('2023-01-01'),
('2022-12-01'),
('2022-11-01'),
('2022-10-01')
```

As you alluded to, you *could* use some Dynamic SQL to achieve this:

```
declare @CurrentMonth nvarchar(10) =   (select convert(varchar,max([Date]),23) from #sourceTable)
declare @LastMonth nvarchar(10) =      (select convert(varchar,dateadd(month,-1,max([Date])),23) from #sourceTable)
declare @ThreeMonthsAgo nvarchar(10) = (select convert(varchar,dateadd(month,-2,max([Date])),23) from #sourceTable)
declare @FourMonthsAgo nvarchar(10) =  (select convert(varchar,dateadd(month,-3,max([Date])),23) from #sourceTable)
declare @FiveMonthsAgo nvarchar(10) =  (select convert(varchar,dateadd(month,-4,max([Date])),23) from #sourceTable)

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
    'create table newTable (['+ @CurrentMonth + '] int, [' 
    + @LastMonth + '] int, ['
    + @ThreeMonthsAgo + '] int, ['
    + @FourMonthsAgo + '] int, ['
    + @FiveMonthsAgo + '] int)'

exec (@sql)
```

This results in a table being created as you wish, with the following SQL command for this particular example data:

```
create table newTable ([2023-07-01] int, [2023-06-01] int, [2023-05-01] int, [2023-04-01] int, [2023-03-01] int)
```

[image: Resulttable]